# How do I transfer EditText information to another activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-edittext

I am trying to send information typed in an EditText of one activity to another activity, and then display it in a TextView.

The code which sends the information:

```
EditText ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.soeg_vare);
String s = ed.getText().toString();

public void onClick(View v)
{
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Vare.this, Vare_resultat.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("SOEG_VARE",s);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Code that receives the information:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String var = i.getStringExtra("SOEG_VARE");
int convert = Integer.parseInt(var);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move this line inside the onClick method:

```
String s = ed.getText().toString();
```

Right now s is getting set the same time you initialize the editText and not getting looked at again when button is pushed.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a probability where your EditText is still empty when you call

```
String s = ed.getText().toString();
```

Try this:

```
EditText ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.soeg_vare);

public void onClick(View v){
    String s = ed.getText().toString();
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Vare.this, Vare_resultat.class);
    myIntent.putExtra(s, s);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Code that receives information:

```
String s = "";
s = getIntent().getExtras().getString(s);
int convert = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer!
This activity is in another activity. I got activity "A", "B" and "C" and i need to transfer information between "B" and "C". But with this code when i try to access "B" from a button in "A" the app stop working. Without the code I can easy get to activity B.

Answer (score 0):

[Solution by the original asker](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16743475/4):

> Code that sends:
>
> ```
> private void addButtonListener() {
>     final Button soeg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.soeg);
>     final EditText ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.soeg_vare);
>     soeg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>             Intent send_soeg = new Intent(Vare.this, Vare_resultat.class);
>             String s = ed.getText().toString();
>             send_soeg.putExtra("SEND_SØG", s);
>             startActivity(send_soeg);
>         }
>     });
> }
> ```
>
> Code that receives:
>
> ```
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_vare_resultat);        
>     TextView modtag_soeg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.modtag_soeg);
>     modtag_soeg.setText("Du søgte efter " + getIntent().getExtras().getString("SEND_SØG"));
> }
> ```